# remove the first zeros of phone input TextFormField of type numbers flutter

Tags: flutter, textformfield

how can i remove the first zeros of phone number like 00963 and 031 and so on in flutter inside `TextFormField`   ?

 here is my code of the`TextFormField` :

```
TextFormField(
             keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              onSaved: (input) => _con.user.phone = input,
             ),
```

my question is not to prevent the user enter the zeros but to get it with phone number without first zeros if the user entered it or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove all first zeros from phone number just use this regex expression:

```
 new RegExp(r'^0+')
```

^ - match the beginning of a line

0+ - match the zero digit character one or more times

Final code for your TextFormField:

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
  onSaved: (input) => _con.user.phone = input.replaceFirst(new RegExp(r'^0+'), '');,
),
```

Answer (score 7):

The above answer is correct but if you using `**TextFormField**` following example will be worth,

```
TextFormField(
   controller: familyMemberPhoneController,
   inputFormatters: [
     FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9]')),
     //To remove first '0'
     FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'^0+')),
     //To remove first '94' or your country code
     FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(r'^94+')),
                  ],
...
```

Comment: Correct approach. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
      String phone = '000345';
      String editedPhone = phone.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'^0+'), "");
      print(phone);
      print(editedPhone);
```

Will print:

```
000345
345
```

Answer (score 0):

```
inputFormatters: [
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
            FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('^0+'))
          ]
```