# How to get rid from leading 0 (zero) in TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to remove 0 numbers without loosing your cursor position.

[image]

Comment: This might be the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64368082/12913325) you are looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
inputFormatters: [
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('^0+'))
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  TextField(
    controller: controller,
    onChanged: (value) {
      var selection = controller.selection;
      final RegExp regexp = new RegExp(r'^0+(?=.)');
      var match = regexp.firstMatch(value);

      var matchLengh = match?.group(0)?.length ?? 0;
      if (matchLengh != 0) {
        controller.text = value.replaceAll(regexp, '');
        controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(
          TextPosition(
            offset: math.min(matchLengh, selection.extent.offset),
          ),
        );
      }
    },
    // keyboardType and inputFormatters not realy needed in this case but maybe usefull
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
    ],
    ...
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also try to convert string into int or double to get rid out of leading zeros, like below example.

```
TextField(
  controller: controller,
  onChanged: (value) {
    controller.text = int.parse(value).toString();
  },
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
  ],
  ....
)
```